# Issue with non-integer node positions after loading scene from a file in Xcode

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, rounding, skscene

I have had a strange issue which I thought I would share. Although work-arounds are fairly simple, they are a bit tedious, and I was wondering whether there was a better way.

I designed a SpriteKit scene using the scene editor, loaded the scene and performed some custom logic in custom class initialisers. This involved creating some new nodes and comparing node positions and adding some integer offsets to the node positions.

Strangely, I found that although the node positions were specified throughout as integers in the scene editor, they came out as non-integer (as shown in the debugger).

Specifically, I had a node with the x value:

```
96.000122
```

This appears to be some binary fraction, so obviously a low bit is set somewhere. I say again, in the scene editor it appears as "96".

The trouble with this as I see it is two fold:

1. Comparisons can fail.
2. It is possible SpriteKit has to do unnecessary anti-aliasing of the image (if it is already pixel aligned).

Are there elegant solutions to round all the positions off in the scene file, or is it something that has to be done manually?

Comment: You can write an extension ... But comparing floats (position.x and y are CGFloats) is probably not what you want... Can you define in what situation you have to compare two floats ?

Comment: Just some logic I wrote. I stack some nodes and then have a method that unhides one specific node and hides all the others in the same position. But it could be anything.

Comment: Yeah but comparing floats can be problematic as you can see. What you are seeing might happen when sprite has dynamic physics body (remove physics body completely and see what happens) . Also it may happen because of rounding errors I guess (which is the case in many engines). Still comparing floats to determine if nodes are at the same position is not a good idea IMO. You should calculate the distance between two nodes and decide  what is considered as the "same position" eg. if two nodes are 0.01 point away from each other, are they considered as they sharing them same position or not...

Comment: And when I say distance, I mean distance between `nodeA.position` and `nodeB.position`

Comment: Yeah - I know comparing floats is not usually good, but a float with an integer in it has a clearly defined value and should be safe. But even without the compare issue, it still is a bad thing to have a point that you think is aligned not aligned for the other reason stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, as suggested, I wrote an extension to round all of the positions:

```
extension SKNode {
    func fixUp() {
        for child in children {
            child.position = CGPoint(
                                 x: round(child.position.x * 4) / 4,
                                 y: round(child.position.y * 4) / 4)
            child.fixUp()
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, I round to quarter points, but this is arbitrary; it could be smaller as only very tiny displacements fail to show up in the scene editor.

I call this in the `init` function.